# CASE statement when searching on a string

Tags: sql, case

I'm attempting this

```
SELECT
    URI_QUERY,
    (CASE
        WHEN URI_QUERY LIKE %'start'% THEN 'START'
        WHEN URI_QUERY LIKE %'terminate'% THEN 'TERMINATE'
        ELSE NULL
    END),
FROM prof_data.FACT_WEBLOG
WHERE uri_ID IN (
    SELECT uri_id
    FROM prof_data.dim_weblog_uri
    WHERE uri LIKE '%/px/track/PRM%'
  )
```

with no success.  Is it possible to use a CASE statement when searching on a string field?  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What problem are you getting?

Comment: `WHEN URI_QUERY LIKE %'start'% THEN 'START' ` has the `%` outside of your single quotes, is that a type-o in your question or your query?

Answer (score 3):

use `LIKE '%start%'` instead of `LIKE %'start'%`. Same issue at `%'terminate'%`

Comment: Thanks so much for the responses.  It was an error / typo on my part.  Its working as expected now.